# Premature field validation in Django migrations

Tags: django, migration

I have the following issue:

I work on a Django app that has a primary DB and now we are adding a secondary DB for syncing only some of the data in it. When I tried to run the migrations, I got an error: null value in column 'field_2' violates not-null constraint. And here is the issue:

The model:

```
class A(models.Model):
   field_1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   field_2 = models.BooleanField(default=True) # added later

   field_3 = models.BooleanField(default=True) # added later
```

and 4 migrations (well, more, but those don't count):

0001 - a related model is created

0002 - model A is created and the relation is created (ForeignKey)

0003 - field_2 is added to model A

0004 - field_3 is added to model A

However when I run migrate on the new DB, the migration stops at migration 0002 with the error mentioned above:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "field_2" violates not-null constraint

even though the field is created in a later migration. 
I don't know hot to even begin a workaround this issue.

Edit:

Migration 0001:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration): 
 initial = True
 dependencies = []
 operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='B',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('year', models.IntegerField()),
                ('active', models.BooleanField(default=True)),

            ],
        ) 
    ]
```

Migration 0002:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration): 

 dependencies = ['app', '0001']
 operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='A',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('field_1', models.BooleanField(default=False))
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='b',
            name='a',
            field=models.OneToOneField(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='app.B'),
        ),
    ]
```

Migration 0003:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration): 

 dependencies = ['app', '0002']

 operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='a',
            name='field_2',
            field=models.BooleanField(default=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Migration 0004:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration): 

 dependencies = ['app', '0003']

 operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='a',
            name='field_3',
            field=models.BooleanField(default=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Migrated: 0001

Comment: Do the migrations mention dependencies in the right order?  It seems like 0002 is being run but `field_2` already exists in the database before 0003 is even run.  Or maybe the migrations were run and just not recorded properly in the `django_migrations` table?

Comment: the order based on dependencies is correct and the DB is empty when running the migrations

Comment: How does "field_2" exist then when running 0002?

Comment: @TimTisdall that's what I'm trying to find out :))

Comment: break it down into steps...  run just the first migration (`python manage.py migrate [APPNAME] 0001_whatever`) and check the database table structure.  Also, post the content of 0001 and 0002 in your question.

Comment: You should add the `dependencies` too.  Also, the beginning of the question says the error is on `field_3` but later you say it's `field_2`.  I can't see any issue with what you've presented, though.

Comment: @TimTisdall yes, I misstyped first, sorry. I have added the dependencies also